# How to use my own file as a default module in Python3?

Tags: python-3.4

```
import myfile
function1(2,3,4)
```

How can i use my file as a default module so that I can use it just by entering import myfilename without specifying

```
import sys   
sys.path.insert(0 ,'/dir1/dir2')    
import myfile    
myfile.function1()
```

Comment: Put the directory of your module in `PYTHONPATH` variable

Comment: Don't add images of code (especially such a tiny snippit like you just showed) Always include typed codesamples so people can check your work